# Oracle Apex and Checkboxes with p_v10 names

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm working with Oracle's APEX. I've iterated through Check-boxes before, but this one has really baffled me.

I've taken a look at the source code for my checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="P16_MANY_IRS_0" name="p_v10" value="104" checked="checked"   /><label for="P16_MANY_IRS_0">3041</label></td><td>
<input type="checkbox" id="P16_MANY_IRS_1" name="p_v10" value="102"    /><label for="P16_MANY_IRS_1">3042</label></td><td>
<input type="checkbox" id="P16_MANY_IRS_2" name="p_v10" value="103"    /><label for="P16_MANY_IRS_2">3043</label></td><td>
<input type="checkbox" id="P16_MANY_IRS_3" name="p_v10" value="101"    /><label for="P16_MANY_IRS_3">3045</label></td></tr></table>
```

These checkboxes aren't part of any form.

Usually the `name` of checkboxes are an `f` number, but these are `p_v`'s.

The real problem is that I cannot use PL/SQL to get the value of the selected checkboxes

`apex_application.g_fxx` doesn't work and I've searched everywhere to see if there is a way to loop through `p_v` items, much like the `.g_f` cursor.

Comment: Are these page items you declared through apex? What do you mean with "aren't part of any form": not in <form> tags (that'd be really odd) or simply because you created these items on a non-"form" page? Are these checkboxes part of one checkbox item with multiple values per chance?

Comment: Spot on, The items were created in a non-form page and were not created using the form wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checkboxes wrapped in fieldset with id="P16_MANY_IRS". After submit, in your PL/SQL code you may access to the value of checkboxes by `x := :P16_MANY_IRS;` Value will be smth like: "101:102:104" - it means that 3 checkboxes (having return values 101, 102, and 104) was checked.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35125/item_types001.htm#sthref2968 - read this. `Displayed using a list of values. A list of values is required for items displayed as check boxes. The value corresponding to a checked box is returned in a single colon-delimited string.`